# Set AutoCommit False across multiple DAO spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, rollback

I am newbie in implementing JDBC. I am building a Registration page in which I need to insert rows into multiple tables.

For every table, I am using DAO and in one of services class I am calling all DAO's insert methods. In every DAO insert method, I am creating new connection using datasource and executing.

Now, If any error occurs while inserting I want to rollback all insert statements.

I know there was

```
   connection.setAutoCommit(false)
```

**Now, How can I create connection once and resuse the same in other DAO's. So that, I can use savepoints and Rollback mechanisms**

Is there any otherway otherthan sending sending connection as parameter.

How could I achieve this?

Below is the sample code from services page:

```
     Sucessfull = firstDAO.save(firstDAOObj);
    if(Sucessfull){
        Sucessfull = secondDAO.save(secondDAOObj);
    }
    if(Sucessfull){
        Sucessfull = thirdDAO.save(thirdDAOObj);
    }
```

Comment: you are getting some strange answers here. i would check out some example applications written with spring.

Comment: @NathanHughes, Guide me if you find any example applications,

Comment: You may want to refer to Spring's [Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
try{
   //Assume a valid connection object conn
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

   String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employees  " +
                "VALUES (106, 20, 'Rita', 'Tez')";
   stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);  
   //Submit a malformed SQL statement that breaks
   String SQL = "INSERTED IN Employees  " +
                "VALUES (107, 22, 'Sita', 'Singh')";
   stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
   // If there is no error.
   conn.commit();
}catch(SQLException se){
   // If there is any error.
   conn.rollback();
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, I want to create the connection once and want to resue the same in all other DAO so that I will use savepoints and autocommit feature...Could you please look into that

Comment: I have edited the answer. The commit() and rollback() can be use accordingly.

Comment: In above example, both sql statements are in one method, but we have different statements in different classes, and we want to use same connection...

Comment: Then create object of the class and call the methods that have the sql queries. pass the connection as a parameter. Get the state of the execution and throw exception if there is an error.

Comment: remember to call all the methods within the try block

Comment: Is there any other way otherthan sending conn as a parameter...In spring MVC

Comment: create the conn globally. But some times it may lead to some issues. make sure not use the same conn created to insert for other activities like delete or edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using a DAO per table (I assume all of your tables are in the same database).  I would probably use a single DAO.  I also would not use a separate connection for each call.  Here is a general template I use for this kind of thing:

I put this at the top of my DAO:

```
private DataSource myDs= new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("<string name of your datasource>");
private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(myDs);
private SimpleJdbcTemplate sjt = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(myDs);
```

Then further down I have something like this in a method where I pass in the objects that contain the data that I want to insert.  This DAO method would be called by your service layer class:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
try {
    // put all of your inserts in here using the SimpleJdbcTemplate 
    // that was declared above

    transactionManager.commit(status);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    try {
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    } catch (Throwable t2) {
        log.error("Error rolling back transaction", t2);
    }
    throw new DataAccessException(t);
}
```

With Spring there are other ways to do transactions one of which includes annotations but that can be a bit more complicated.  I would recommend looking into that for your future applications.

Comment: I want to group all the table related statements in one class, so I have implemented separate DAO for each table. There will be many tables in my DB, is there any other way to achieve the above

Comment: @SpringUser - I really don't think that having a separate DAO per table is a good design.  If you have 50 tables in your database, then you end up with 50 DAO's.  Having said that, have you used Spring annotations before?  You want to google Spring database transaction annotations for the version of Spring that you are using.  They do an excellent job of explaining it.  That will allow you to put the appropriate annotation on the DAO methods that you want to participate in the transaction across multiple DAO classes.

Comment: Thanks @Troy, I will search for Spring database transaction annotations and get back to you in case of any questions.